# Unable to set the value of an NSDecimalNumber attribute of a Core Data model in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I've got a core data model called AccountMO, which contains an attribute of NSSet? called holdings which contains a set of another core data model called HoldingMO. HoldingMO has an attribute called holdingValue which is an NSDecimalNumber type.

The AccountMO model has an attribute called accountValue of NSDecimalNumber type, which is supposed to be the sum of the HoldingMO.holdingValue attribute.

I gave up trying to use Core Data derived attributes because the compiler just won't build if there's more than one derived attribute in a model, and I need several summary attributes for other NSSet attributes as well.

I can calculate the sum of HoldingMO.holdingValue like this:

```
let sum = holdings?.value(forKeyPath: "@sum.holdingValue")
```

This results in that ever not so useful type "Any", which I have to convert to NSDecimal like so:

```
let sum = holdings?.value(forKeyPath: "@sum.holdingValue") as! Decimal
accountValue = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: sum)
```

I've also tried to do it like this:

```
        if holdings?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
            let hlds = holdings as! Set<HoldingMO>
            let sum = hlds.map {$0.holdingValue}.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.decimalValue }
            accountValue = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: sum)
        }
```

But either way where I try to set accountValue the app always crashes the app with:
"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

I've searched a lot of solutions, and it seems this is caused by forcing an unwrap on an optional property. I've done the best I can to eliminate any optionals, (other than the optional NSSet? for the holdings set.)

Any ideas?

Here's the AccountMO model:

```
    //
//  AccountMO+CoreDataProperties.swift
//  AdvisorBook v3
//
//  Created by Chris Browning on 6/28/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Browning Financial, Inc. All rights reserved.
//
//

import Foundation
import CoreData
import Cocoa

    extension AccountMO {
    
        @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<AccountMO> {
            return NSFetchRequest<AccountMO>(entityName: "Account")
        }
    
        @NSManaged public var accountName: String?
        @NSManaged public var accountNumber: String?
        @NSManaged public var accountRegType: TypeOfAccountReg
        @NSManaged public var accountTitle: String?
        @NSManaged public var accountType: TypeOfAccount
        @NSManaged public var accountValue: NSDecimalNumber
        @NSManaged public var billingType: TypeOfBilling
        @NSManaged public var cash: NSDecimalNumber?
        @NSManaged public var clearingFirm: TypeOfClearingFirm
        @NSManaged public var closedDate: Date?
        @NSManaged public var openDate: Date?
        @NSManaged public var company: String?
        @NSManaged public var cost: NSDecimalNumber?
        @NSManaged public var created: NSDate
        @NSManaged public var fee: NSDecimalNumber?
        @NSManaged public var gain: NSDecimalNumber?
        @NSManaged public var gainPerc: NSDecimalNumber?
        @NSManaged public var gc: NSDecimalNumber?
        @NSManaged public var holdingCount: Int32
        @NSManaged public var minCash: NSDecimalNumber?
        @NSManaged public var modified: NSDate
        @NSManaged public var restricted: Bool
        @NSManaged public var status: TypeOfStatus
        @NSManaged public var subNumber: String?
        @NSManaged public var tradeCount: Int32
        @NSManaged public var ytdGC: NSDecimalNumber?
        @NSManaged public var ytdGCPerc: NSDecimalNumber?
        @NSManaged public var ytdTradeCount: Int32
        @NSManaged public var ytdYear: Int32
        @NSManaged public var qualified: TypeOfQualified
        @NSManaged public var advisors: NSSet?
        @NSManaged public var contacts: NSSet?
        @NSManaged public var holdings: NSSet?
        @NSManaged public var trades: NSSet?
        @NSManaged public var feeSchedule: FeeScheduleMO?
        
           override public func awakeFromInsert() {
            let app = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            
               let moc : NSManagedObjectContext = ((NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext)
               let advisorFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Advisor")
            let investFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Investment")
            investFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "symbol == %@", "CASH")
               do {
                   let fetchedAdvisors = try moc.fetch(advisorFetch) as! [AdvisorMO]
                
                   if fetchedAdvisors.count > 0 {
                       let advisor = fetchedAdvisors[0]
                       addToAdvisors(advisor)
                    
                    let fetchedInvestments = try moc.fetch(investFetch) as! [InvestmentMO]
                    if fetchedAdvisors.count > 0 {
                        let holding = app.myViewController.newHolding()
                        holding.coreCash = true
                        holding.investment = fetchedInvestments[0]
                        holding.investedDate = Date()
                        addToHoldings(holding)
                        app.myViewController.accountHoldingsArrayController.defaultFetchRequest()
                        }
                   }
                   created = NSDate()
                   modified = NSDate()
                
                
               } catch {
                   fatalError("Failed to fetch advisors: \(error)")
               }
               
           }
           
           @objc public var statusString: String? {
               get {
                   return status.displayName
               }
               set {
                   status = TypeOfStatus(withname: newValue ?? "OPEN") ?? TypeOfStatus.OPEN
               }
           }
        @objc public var clearingFirmString: String? {
            get {
                return clearingFirm.displayName
            }
            set {
                clearingFirm = TypeOfClearingFirm(withname: newValue ?? "DIRECT") ?? TypeOfClearingFirm.DIRECT
            }
        }
           @objc public var billingTypeString: String? {
               get {
                   return billingType.displayName
               }
               set {
                   billingType = TypeOfBilling(withname: newValue ?? "COMMISSION") ?? TypeOfBilling.COMMISSION
               }
           }
           @objc public var accountTypeString: String? {
               get {
                   return accountType.displayName
               }
               set {
                   accountType = TypeOfAccount(withname: newValue ?? "CASH") ?? TypeOfAccount.CASH
               }
           }
           @objc public var accountRegTypeString: String? {
               get {
                   return accountRegType.displayName
               }
               set {
                   accountRegType = TypeOfAccountReg(withname: newValue ?? "OTHER") ?? TypeOfAccountReg.OTHER
               }
           }
           @objc public var qualifiedString: String? {
               get {
                   return qualified.displayName
               }
               set {
                   willChangeValue(forKey: "qualified")
                   if newValue?.starts(with: "NON") ?? false {
                       qualified = TypeOfQualified.NONQUALIFIED
                   } else {
                       qualified = TypeOfQualified.QUALIFIED
                   }
                   didChangeValue(forKey: "qualified")
               }
           }
        
        func refresh() {
            if holdings?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
                //accountValue = holdings?.value(forKeyPath: "@sum.holdingValue?") as! NSDecimalNumber
                let numberString = accountNumber ?? "No number"
                let titleString = accountTitle ?? "No title"
                let accountString = numberString + " " + titleString
                print(accountString)
                
                
                
                if holdings?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
                    let hlds = holdings as! Set<HoldingMO>
                    let sum = hlds.map {$0.holdingValue}.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.decimalValue }
                    accountValue = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: sum)
                }
                
                
            }
            
        }
        
        func sumHoldings() throws -> Decimal {
            return holdings?.value(forKeyPath: "@sum.holdingValue") as! Decimal
        }
        
        override public func willSave() {
            if changedValues()["modified"] == nil {
                modified = NSDate()
            } else {
                super.willSave()
            }
        }
        override public func awakeFromFetch() {
            //refresh()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Generated accessors for advisors
    extension AccountMO {
    
        @objc(addAdvisorsObject:)
        @NSManaged public func addToAdvisors(_ value: AdvisorMO)
    
        @objc(removeAdvisorsObject:)
        @NSManaged public func removeFromAdvisors(_ value: AdvisorMO)
    
        @objc(addAdvisors:)
        @NSManaged public func addToAdvisors(_ values: NSSet)
    
        @objc(removeAdvisors:)
        @NSManaged public func removeFromAdvisors(_ values: NSSet)
    
    }
    
    // MARK: Generated accessors for contacts
    extension AccountMO {
    
        @objc(addContactsObject:)
        @NSManaged public func addToContacts(_ value: ContactMO)
    
        @objc(removeContactsObject:)
        @NSManaged public func removeFromContacts(_ value: ContactMO)
    
        @objc(addContacts:)
        @NSManaged public func addToContacts(_ values: NSSet)
    
        @objc(removeContacts:)
        @NSManaged public func removeFromContacts(_ values: NSSet)
    
    }
    
    // MARK: Generated accessors for holdings
    extension AccountMO {
    
        @objc(addHoldingsObject:)
        @NSManaged public func addToHoldings(_ value: HoldingMO)
    
        @objc(removeHoldingsObject:)
        @NSManaged public func removeFromHoldings(_ value: HoldingMO)
    
        @objc(addHoldings:)
        @NSManaged public func addToHoldings(_ values: NSSet)
    
        @objc(removeHoldings:)
        @NSManaged public func removeFromHoldings(_ values: NSSet)
    
    }
    
    // MARK: Generated accessors for trades
    extension AccountMO {
    
        @objc(addTradesObject:)
        @NSManaged public func addToTrades(_ value: TradeMO)
    
        @objc(removeTradesObject:)
        @NSManaged public func removeFromTrades(_ value: TradeMO)
    
        @objc(addTrades:)
        @NSManaged public func addToTrades(_ values: NSSet)
    
        @objc(removeTrades:)
        @NSManaged public func removeFromTrades(_ values: NSSet)
    
    }
```

And the HoldingMO model:

```
//
//  HoldingMO+CoreDataProperties.swift
//  AdvisorBook v3
//
//  Created by Chris Browning on 5/20/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Browning Financial, Inc. All rights reserved.
//
//

import Foundation
import CoreData


extension HoldingMO {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<HoldingMO> {
        return NSFetchRequest<HoldingMO>(entityName: "Holding")
    }

    @NSManaged public var cost: NSDecimalNumber
    @NSManaged public var coreCash: Bool
    @NSManaged public var costPrice: NSDecimalNumber
    @NSManaged public var created: NSDate
    @NSManaged public var gain: NSDecimalNumber
    @NSManaged public var gainPerc: NSDecimalNumber
    @NSManaged public var holdingAccountType: Int32
    @NSManaged public var holdingPrice: NSDecimalNumber
    @NSManaged public var holdingValue: NSDecimalNumber
    @NSManaged public var investedDate: Date?
    @NSManaged public var isStockOrMF: Bool
    @NSManaged public var isStockOrMFOrUIT: Bool
    @NSManaged public var modified: NSDate
    @NSManaged public var override: Bool
    @NSManaged public var quantity: NSDecimalNumber
    @NSManaged public var soldDate: Date?
    @NSManaged public var status: TypeOfStatus
    @NSManaged public var subAccount: String?
    @NSManaged public var account: AccountMO?
    @NSManaged public var investment: InvestmentMO?
    @NSManaged public var trades: NSSet?
    
    @objc public var change: NSDecimalNumber? {
        get {
            //let amt = (investment?.priceChange?.decimalValue ?? 0) as NSDecimalNumber
            return _change
        }
        set {
            _change = newValue ?? 0
        }
    }
    
    @objc public var statusString: String? {
        get {
            return status.displayName ?? "OPEN"
        }
        set {
            status = TypeOfStatus(withname: newValue ?? "OPEN") ?? TypeOfStatus.OPEN
            hideClosed = isOpen()
        }
    }
    
    @objc public var hideClosed: Bool {
        get {
            return _hideclosed
        }
        set {
            _hideclosed = newValue
        }
    }
    
    override public func awakeFromInsert() {
        created = NSDate()
        modified = NSDate()
        investedDate = Date()
    }
    
    override public func awakeFromFetch() {        
        refresh()
    }
    
    func refresh() {
        if status == TypeOfStatus.OPEN {
            if investment != nil {
                holdingPrice = investment?.price as! NSDecimalNumber
                let amt = (investment?.priceChange.decimalValue ?? 0) as NSDecimalNumber
                change = quantity.multiplying(by: amt)
                isStockOrMF = ((investment?.isStockOrMF) != nil)
                let val = holdingPrice.multiplying(by: quantity)
                holdingValue = val
                holdingValue = holdingPrice.multiplying(by: quantity)
                if investment?.investmentType == TypeOfInvestment.CASH {
                    cost = holdingValue
                }
                gain = holdingValue.subtracting(cost)
                print(gain)
                if gain.decimalValue != 0 {
                    gainPerc = gain.dividing(by: cost)
                } else {
                    gainPerc = 0
                }
                modified = NSDate()
                account?.refresh()
            }
        } else {
            if investment != nil {
                isStockOrMF = ((investment?.isStockOrMF) != nil)
                holdingValue = holdingPrice.multiplying(by: quantity )
                if investment?.investmentType == TypeOfInvestment.CASH {
                    cost = holdingValue
                }
                gain = holdingValue.subtracting(cost )
                gainPerc = gain.dividing(by: cost )
                modified = NSDate()
                account?.refresh()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override public func willSave() {
        if changedValues()["modified"] == nil {
            modified = NSDate()
        } else {
            super.willSave()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Generated accessors for trades
extension HoldingMO {

    @objc(addTradesObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToTrades(_ value: TradeMO)

    @objc(removeTradesObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromTrades(_ value: TradeMO)

    @objc(addTrades:)
    @NSManaged public func addToTrades(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeTrades:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromTrades(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by just dropping the use of the Core Data attribute in favor of a simple @objc property like this:

```
var _accountval: NSDecimalNumber = 0    
@objc public var accountVal: NSDecimalNumber {
        get {
            return _accountval
        }
        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "accountVal")
            _accountval = newValue
            didChangeValue(forKey: "accountVal")
        }
    }
```

Instead of

```
@NSManaged public var accountValue: NSDecimalNumber
```

Now I can call this:

```
func refresh() {
    if holdings != nil && holdings?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
        var sum: Decimal = 0
        for holding in holdings as! Set<HoldingMO> {
            if holding.isOpen() {
                sum += holding.holdingValue.decimalValue
            }
        }
        accountVal = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: sum)
    }
}
```

From:

```
override public func awakeFromFetch() {
    refresh()
}
```

Which keeps the new accountVal property and bindings up to date. Since the previous Core Data attribute was "Transient" anyway there's no reason to use it when I can easily just use an @objc property instead. Much easier!